# Adding newline and spacing in watson conversation output (JSON)

Tags: json, watson-conversation

I want the watson conversation to give an output like:

---

I can solve the problems for the following products.

1  Air Conditioner

2  Refrigerator

3  Washing Machine

---

I am trying the following in JSON. But I am getting all the text cramped together.

---

{
  "output": {
    "text": "I can solve the problems for the following products.\n\n1\tAir Conditioner\n2\tRefrigerator\n3\tWashing Machine"
  }
}

---

I have also tried \n and \t which is also unsuccessful. Is there any way to get the text properly spaced in the JSON *text* tag. (I used the conversation tool to everything)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer!!

add

"br" tags in the simple format of JSON. It is not reflected on the test chat, the change is only reflected on deploying it in an app

Comment: That sounds more like HTML not being sanitized in the app deployment you're using, especially since the test chat doesn't show the line breaks. I wouldn't depend on it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
{
    "output": {
        "text": ["I can solve the problems for the following products.",
            "1\tAir Conditioner", "2\tRefrigerator", "3\tWashing Machine"
        ]
    }
}
```

As per documentation:

> To specify more than one statement that you want to display on separate lines, define the output as a JSON array.
>
> The first sentence is displayed on one line, and the second sentence is displayed as a new line below it.

Source: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-build.html#responses

Comment: it will respond with with only one of these lines at a time.  it doesn't return all of them with line breaks

Comment: Actually, it returns all of them at once as an array, not with line breaks. The line breaks you add manually in your view.