# How to add a new line in IBM Watson chatbot conversation?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

Currently I'm working with the chatbot service provided by the IBM Watson Coversation api. Now I'm facing a problem, related to adding a new line in the text reply from the chatbot. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far, including the code in which you want to add the new line.

Comment: http://conversation-test-shinoy.au-syd.mybluemix.net/ you can find the bot here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding newline and spacing in watson conversation output (JSON)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40023329/adding-newline-and-spacing-in-watson-conversation-output-json)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in this case, you can use `HTML` for that, inside conversation flow with `<br>`.

**Check my example:**

[image]

**You can see that does not work in "Try it out":**

[image]

**But if you open with a browser, you see that work:**

[image]

**Check JSON example:**

```
{
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "Hey, <br>Can I help you?",
        "",
        ""
      ],
      "selection_policy": "random"
    }
  }
}
```

You can use other tags, example: `<button>`, `<id>`, etc.