# Watson Conversation Service and Carriage Returns

Tags: carriage-return, watson-conversation

I've got a dialog in IBM's Watson Conversation Service. I have a node that has this in it:

```
        "output": {
            "text": {
                "values": [
                    "Pick a fruit* Apples* Oranges* Pears"
                ]
            }
        },
```

This is Markdown format and is eventually converted to HTML as an unordered list. Markdown requires carriage returns for the parser. So my question is how do I split "values" into multiple lines? I can do sequential and random values but is there a way to to output all lines at once?

My work around is to insert "\n" sequences and then convert to carriage returns via a regex, but this is a hack.

This was possible using Watson WEA 2.0.

Comment: `<br>` It is possible to to insert "\n".[Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42572439/how-to-add-a-new-line-in-ibm-watson-chatbot-conversation)

Comment: The entire line goes into a Markdown parser, so any extra chars have to be removed (like my extra "\\n"'s). Since it is the customer who will be doing this, I want it to be as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

In watson conversation service store all the values of fruit in array. and use

```
<?$array_name.join('<br>')?>
```

it will show all the values of fruits in separate line.